# Is there an R function for separating date & time with AM or PM?

Tags: r, datetime

#NewToR

I have a column that contains date&time like this `"5/2/2016 11:59:59 PM"` and I want to separate them into Date column= `"8/12/2014"` and timecoloumn= `"11:59:59 PM"`.

How can I separate this date and time in R?

this is what I have done and so far, I have separated the date.

```r
weight_log$Date <- as.Date(weight_log$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
weight_log$date <- as.Date(weight_log$Date) #adds date column
```

here is the problem. the below code gives me `"18:00:00"` instead of `"11:59:59 PM"`

```r
#add time column
weight_log$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(weight_log$Date), format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do all this in base R. The key is to *properly* parse and then format:

```
> df <- data.frame(dt=c("5/2/2016 11:59:59 PM", "6/3/2017 01:02:03 AM"))
> df$pt <- strptime(df$dt, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
> df
                    dt                  pt
1 5/2/2016 11:59:59 PM 2016-05-02 23:59:59
2 6/3/2017 01:02:03 AM 2017-06-03 01:02:03
>
```

This used example data (your one point and another) and then *parse* with the proper arguments: note `%I` and `%p` here (see `help(strptime)` for more).

We can then add the two new columns by formatting:

```
> df$day <- format(df$pt, "%Y-%m-%d")
> df$time <- format(df$pt, "%H:%M:%S")
> df
                    dt                  pt        day     time
1 5/2/2016 11:59:59 PM 2016-05-02 23:59:59 2016-05-02 23:59:59
2 6/3/2017 01:02:03 AM 2017-06-03 01:02:03 2017-06-03 01:02:03
>
```

I used ISO format for the output here but you can use other formats as you please.  Standards are good though.

Comment: This syntax creates day and time columns and has the right values for day but the column for time has only  00:00:00 as values.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `extract`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(weight_log, Date, into = c("date", "time"), "^(\\S+)\\s+(.*)")
```

Comment: I tried this syntax and got two columns for date and time which is perfect but the values are NA. so that left me wondering what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

the below worked although it did not leave the AM/PM right beside the time.

df <- df%>% separate(column in the df,c("Date","Time")," ")

df = data frame you are dealing with.
Date = one of the columns in the df that has the time &date